# Checksum of transmitted files with CRC-32C

Tags: c++, centos, synchronization, checksum, crc32

I need to synchronize some files between multiple machines and then use them with my application. The problem I may encounter is file not being completely delivered yet. To solve it I wanted to checksum each file with CRC-32C algorithm.

And here I have a question. **How do I deliver the checksums themselves for each file**? There's a database in my disposal that tells me when to try to read files, so it'd be completely safe to write hash into database first and only then calculate hash for delivered files with my application. But it just feels wrong. What is a standard? How do you usually perform checksum for files when synchronizing them?

Answer (score 1):

Append the CRC to the file. Then when you receive *n* bytes, compute the CRC in the first n-4 bytes, and compare that to the last four bytes. If it matches, there is a high probability there was not an error or omission in the transmission. Then remove the last four bytes.

For additional assurance, you can also append the length of the file to the file, say eight bytes, and check that as well.

(By the way, a CRC is not a checksum. It's a CRC.)